# Set time in sql server always to be the same no matter of day light change

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have in my sql job set date and time as:

```
@active_start_date=20180827, 
@active_end_date=99991231, 
@active_start_time=210200, 
@active_end_time=235959,
```

How can i always have the same start time, in my case **21:02:00** no matter of day light change or time zone change. So this year this time change was on **31st of March** and because i had this time hard coded i didn't get right data in my table.

Comment: If timezones are important, then use a timezone based datatype (`datetimeoffset`), or use UTC times.

Comment: So after 31st March you want the time to become 20:02:00 / 22:02:00?

Comment: I have some time zone in Europe, that is UTC +2 or UTC+3, depending of DST.So i want that date to be always set to UTC in variable @active_start_time. If my current time after 31.3 is 21:02:00 will be in UTC 18:02:00, but on 27.10 will be UTC 19:02:00

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a DATETIMEOFFSET data type.  In addition to the date and time it holds the timezone information, so it is a more accurate representation of the exact time you want.

Comment: can you write an example fro my case?